# Evaluate postfix expression

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I have to write a program that converts infix to postfix and then evaluates the postfix expression. I have done the conversion part. However I am a bit confused about the evaluating part. The method that evaluates the expression takes a Linked List representation of the postfix expression. That's making it a bit confusing for me. The header of the method would be as follows:

```
public static String evaluatePostfix(StringList postfix)
```

So, do I have to iterate through the linked list and evaluate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, how else would you do it?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919656/infix-to-postfix-in-java-using-stack-class/28922026

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to iterate the linked list, and evaluate it. The classic way of evaluating a postfix expression is by using a *stack*. The algorithm is as follows:

- For each element of the list, check its type
- If the element represents a number, push it onto the stack
- If the element is an operation, pop one or two elements off the stack, depending on the kind of the operation, perform the operation, and push the result back onto the stack
- Once the loop is over, there will be a single element on the stack; that is your result.

If at any time your operation cannot find enough arguments on the stack, the expression being evaluated is invalid. Same goes for the situation when the stack does not have exactly one element upon completion of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has become clearer now. Just one question, how would i push back the result of type int back onto my string stack?

Comment: @mzmz95 You shouldn't use a string stack, use an int stack. The `Stack<Integer>` should be entirely separate from the `StringList`, which represents the postfix expression. Create it inside your method before the loop, and it will be discarded when the method is over.

Comment: I have to use a StringStackRefBased. I don't really have a choice.

Comment: @mzmz95 Then you need to convert your `int`s to `String` before pushing the data onto stack, and then converting strings back to `int`s when you pop them for the operation.